# problem with scanning colored pencil artwork for emailing to publisher

Tags: illustration

I am a first time illustrator who has been working for the last year on colored pencil illustrations for a children's book.

I wanted to have the drawings scanned so that I could send them to an agent. The local print shop employee was not able to do anything about the artwork coming out discolored (yellow/green cast) and faded out looking.

Someone mentioned having the work professionally photographed? I'm not very tech savvy so I am not sure how that would help....would there then be another way to send it electronically?

Can you offer me any assistance or insight? I pray all of my work will not have been in vain.

Thank you.....Jackie M

Comment: Relax, scans and photographs need to be color balanced. Start by forming a objective question we can answer. Questions of type "my car isnt working whats wrong with my car" are hard to answer. Give us a sample of the image you got. But realistically since print is a bit color deficent you need to work with the colors a bit anyway. On that note, why on earth didnt you test your worflow before now?

Comment: You may need to consult a design professional. I'm not entirely sure what "local print shop employee" refers to, but if it's the young guy/gal at the FedEx Kinkos (or similar) they *generally* aren't well-educated/experienced in color/reproduction needs and are hired to push buttons more than anything. One *should* be able to get quality scans that closely mimic the original. But ya kinda gotta know what you're doing beyond hitting the `scan` button.

Comment: If the scan just has a colour cast and is only a little faded, there's a possibility it could be fixed using raster image editing software such as Photoshop or GIMP. Can you please share the image, or a portion of the image you had scanned?